# Why do I have two versions of blender?

Tags: installation

I've downloaded blender 2.82 and installed it, but now I have two separate applications, 2.82 and my old one, 2.80. Do I just delete the old one?

Comment: Hello :). Yes, you can uninstall the old 2.8 version. It good to check if 2.82 works well first :).